# Firestore rule split a custom token and see if it matches

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I have custom claims set on users, the claims look like

```
organizations [
  933219123_Project-name,
  311239123_Different-Project-name
]
```

The first part is the `DocumentId` in Firestore. is it possible to split or check up until the `_` via regex or something? I know we can't use loops in rules

I have a rule that works if I don't include the `_Project-name` part of the claim when setting them,

```
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /organizations/{uid}/repositories/{document=**} {
      allow read: if request.auth != null && uid in request.auth.token.organizations
    }
  }
```

However I need both the project ID and name in my claims for the frontend stuff.

Aside from just adding both the ID and name as separate claims (seems wasteful), do I have any other options?

Answer (score 1):

Based on the question, it's possible to use Regular Expressions on strings.

To check how to use the Regex on Firebase, you may refer to [**Firebase Security Rules Regular Expressions**](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/security/database/regex).

I would also recommend to try using [**matches**](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rules/rules.String#matches) and [**split**](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rules/rules.String#split) for the rule to match your expectations.

For reference, I'm able to use `matches`.
Please see below sample:

```
 match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{organizations}/{uid}/repositories/{document=**} {
      allow read: if (request.auth != null && uid in request.auth.token.organizations && organizations.matches(document+'[_]test[-]project'))
    }
  }
```

***Note: Simulated read allowed on Firestore Rules Playground (Tested without the Auth).***

[image: Simulated read allowed without the Auth.]

This will get `DocumentId` before the `_` and `ProjectId` to check whether if the `DocumentID` with the `ProjectID` are in the custom claims list.